# Google Maps Api3 searchbox (places), markers - sort by category on one map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Api3 searchbox (places), markers - sort by category on one map

I want to create custom map, based on this: http://jsfiddle.net/ReneKorss/cLADs/ and google maps API 3 documentation by google.

My current map
http://jsfiddle.net/0r5g8oz5/9/

```
  var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
//    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(legend);
```

When I "uncomment" map.control.... I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

---

How get legend to work on this map?

Comment: Look at the javascript console.  `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`,  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined`

Comment: Thank You for console.log. Now, I must figure it out, how to make this code work.

Comment: After some debuging: http://jsfiddle.net/0r5g8oz5/6/ There is only one more error left: Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined, I'm probably  halfway to finish.

Comment: map is not defined because you don't define map anywhere. You need a `var map;` somewhere. You're missing a lot of `var` statements in general. Check the code thoroughly and make sure you declare all your local variables. In particular, where you assign `marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({...});` you are creating a *global* `marker1` variable. This really needs to be a local variable so your event handler in the same function will pick up the specific `marker1` value for each individual marker.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using the complicated immediately executed function for that event handler so it captures `marker1`. If you use a proper `var` you won't need that and can simplify the event listener code to: `google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () { console.log etc… });` - no need for the extra function-that-returns-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add

```
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(legend);
```

into function initialize.

before closing:

```
function initialize() {

//code here....
}
```

Problem solved